# How to check bracket in json string

Tags: android, json

Hi to every body i write simple app to recieve json from server,i get this string:

```
[]
```

How to check up string,for example :

```
if(result==null)
     ...do some thing
```

Comment: I don't understand what your question is, nor what you're trying to do. Can you explain in more detail, maybe show some more code?

Comment: hi my friend,i get this json from server,bracket get into string,i want to check if server send bracket or empty string i do somthing.

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
if (result == null || result.equals("[]") {
    // do something
}
```